# go http.ListenAndServe doesn't wait for connections looks like it exiting

Tags: go, httpserver

I have a simple app that I expect to be a daemon that waits for connections, but it looks like it doesn't listen and I even can't find it in the process list.

Code:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println("Start Server")
        log.Print("Start Server")
        http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello, World! from linux")
        })
        log.Print("Going to listen")
        if err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil); err != err {
          log.Print("getting error")
          log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("End  Server")
        log.Print("End  Server")
}
```

Compile and run:

```
    xxx@xxx:~/go_test$ CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -gcflags "all=-N -l" -o ./main
    umen@umen:~/go_test$ ./main
Start Server
2023/11/15 07:40:22 Start Server
2023/11/15 07:40:22 Going to listen
End  Server
2023/11/15 07:40:22 End  Server
```

Trying to connect:

```
xxx@xxx:~$ curl http://localhost
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

What am I missing here?

### Update

Removed the Fatal, still it start and stop without listening to get request.

Comment: `ListenAndServe` _always_ returns an error. And it blocks until the server exits.

Comment: You cannot simply listen on privileged ports. Either run your code in privileged mode or use an unprivileged port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`log.Fatal("Going to listen")` terminates your application execution.

References:

- https://pkg.go.dev/log#Fatal

Comment: i fixed it tnx! also update the question , still have problem

Comment: @user63898 now you don't check for errors: see that you have `err != err`, not `err != nil`